# How to sum and multiply mysql two rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two products with same unique code (Database table):

```
+----------------------------------+-----+-------+
|               CODE               | QTY | Price |
+----------------------------------+-----+-------+
| 977b8213fd7s7d0129f4358a75ca967f | 143 | 11.83 |
| 977b8213fd7s7d0129f4358a75ca967f |  31 | 10.48 |
+----------------------------------+-----+-------+
```

I must sum and multiply `QTY` and `Price` to get a total price.

In above example, total price should be 2016.57 (11.83 × 143 + 10.48 × 31 = 2016.57).

I tried this but I get two totals (1691.69 and 2016.57):

```
$code = "977b8213fd7s7d0129f4358a75ca967f";
$ttl=0;

try{
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->openConnection();
    $sql= "SELECT qty*rraate AS sum FROM carrrt WHERE code = :code";
    $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
    $qry -> bindParam(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $qry -> execute();
    while ($qnow = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $ttl += $qnow['sum'];
         echo $ttl;
    }   

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Why am I getting two totals and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your while loop you calculate the total for the first row and echo it, then add the total for the second row to the first and echo that.  The answers to this question give you better solutions, but all you need to do is move the `echo $ttl;` to outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

`SELECT ROUND(SUM(rraate*qty),2) AS sum FROM carrrt WHERE code = :code";`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use an aggregate.

See if this fixes your problem

```
$sql= "SELECT SUM(qty*rraate) AS sum FROM carrrt WHERE code = :code";
```

The `SUM()` in the select I used is called an aggregate, which is the primary way to collect data from every row and combine it into some value.

Unless you use an aggregate, you will get a distinct answer for every row in your table. For more information on aggregates, you can look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)